# Как запретить отправку формы по нажатии кнопки ENTER?

Tags: javascript

В форме кнопка с онкликом.
Нужно запретить отправку формы по нажатии кнопки ENTER.
Можно ли это как-то сделать?

Или чтобы Enter работал также, как
нажатие на кнопку.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ну, например, так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(form).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: А как эту функцию к форме привязать?

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, $(form) вам о чем нибудь говорит?

Comment: Ну то есть привязывать не надо? Я вставил скрипт, но по интеру отправляется.

Comment: ну естественно надо. причем именно к вашей форме, а не к некоей абстрактной form, которую я написал для примера. если у вас есть <form id="myform">, то в скрипте $("myform")

Comment: зачем и return false и preventDefault()???

Comment: у формы есть событие submit....

Comment: event.stopPropagation() забыли ещё добавить

Comment: Если в форме есть `textarea`, то по нажатию enter на них на следующую строку не будет перехода.

Comment: Предложенное решение не работает
NameError: name 'document' is not defined

Answer (score 6):

Без использования дополнительных библиотек типа `jQuery` и т.п. запрет отправки формы по нажатию клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd> можно реализовать следующим образом:

```
<form name="test" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="text1" value="Некоторый текст 1" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="text2" value="Некоторый текст 2" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Отправить" onclick="this.parentNode.submit();"> 
</form>
```

То есть просто убираем `input` с `type="submit"`, добавляя вместо него `input` с `type="button"` и JS-обработчиком нажатия. При нажатии <kbd>Enter</kbd> в любом поле формы она не будет отправлена, поскольку браузер не сможет обнаружить кнопку отправки.

Comment: У меня не работает такое решение. Браузер - хром. Вообще теперь никак не отправляет.

Answer (score 3):

```
form.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 1):

Важно понимать, что если сделать так, в таком случае в textarea не будет работать перенос!

```
form.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

Если есть в форме textarea, лучше сделать вот так

```
form.addEventListener('keydown',function(e) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13 && e.target.type !== 'textarea') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```